# ejb-3.0 customized exception

Tags: exception, ejb-3.0

My ejb3 application running on JBOSS6 already has a customized Exception handler "Ejbexception.java"  which extends Exception class

I  want to  use the same to trap Exceptions with some number and send back the same to the Client Code for handling gentel message .

ex:

```
try{
     .....
}catch(SQLException ex){
   throw new EjbException("1001");
}
```

Now **HOWto get the "1001" on the Client Code  ?????**

thx in advance
karthik

Answer (score 0):

Did you write this Ejbexception class yourself? If so, that's a poor choice of name, because there's already a [javax.ejb.EJBException](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBException.html) in the library. However, it will work: when you throw it, the container will transport it to the client, who can then catch it. The string you inserted will be available from the exception's `getMessage()` method, just like normal.

If you're actually throwing a javax.ejb.EJBException here, then things are slightly different. That exception is aimed at the container, not the client. I actually don't know how it's made visible to the client. My suggestion would be to switch to using a custom exception, which the container will then pass to the client.